# multiple data.table columns to one column of vectors

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table like this:

```
tab = data.table(V1 = c('a', 'b', 'c'),
           V2 = c('d', 'e', 'f'),
           V3 = c('g', 'h', 'i'),
           id = c(1,2,3))
```

From the columns V1,V2,V3 of this table, I'd like to get for row i a vector of `c(V1[i],V2[i], V3[i])`

I can get a list of the desired vectors like this:

```
lapply(1:tab[, .N], function(x) tab[x, c(V1, V2, V3)])
```

Which returns:

```
[[1]]
[1] "a" "d" "g"

[[2]]
[1] "b" "e" "h"

[[3]]
[1] "c" "f" "i"
```

But I think this is probably slow and not very data.table-like.

Also, I'd like to generalize it, do that I don't have explicitly type V1, V2, V3, but rather pass a vector of column names to be processed this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this?

```
> asplit(unname(tab[, V1:V3]), 1)
[[1]]
"a" "d" "g"

[[2]]
"b" "e" "h"

[[3]]
"c" "f" "i"
```

Comment: I think `unname` will remove the names attribute `asplit(unname(tab[, V1:V3]), 1)`

Comment: @akrun Good advice! Thank you bro :)

Answer (score 3):

```
as.list(transpose(tab[, .(V1, V2, V3)]))
```

Or as a function

```
tdt <- function(DT, cols) as.list(transpose(DT[, .SD, .SDcols = cols]))

tdt(tab, c('V1', 'V2', 'V3'))

# $V1
# [1] "a" "d" "g"
# 
# $V2
# [1] "b" "e" "h"
# 
# $V3
# [1] "c" "f" "i"
```

Comment: Will this work well even for large tables with millions of rows?

Comment: @ira I think it is a very fast way to accomplish the task but not sure how memory efficient it is.

Comment: @ira tested around a bit with a 10 million row file and for that database this solution took about 1.5 minutes to finish compared to 1 minute for ThomasIsCoding's solution

Answer (score 3):

Using `split`

```
split(as.matrix(tab[, V1:V3]), tab$id)
$`1`
[1] "a" "d" "g"

$`2`
[1] "b" "e" "h"

$`3`
[1] "c" "f" "i"
```

Comment: And if I wanted to store the result in the data table as column of type list, would I still need to turn all three columns into a matrix?

Comment: @ira You may also do `tab[, new_col := split(as.matrix(.SD), id), .SDcols = V1:V3]` if the intention is to create a new list column

Answer (score 1):

```r
tab[, 1:3] |> transpose() |> as.list()

$V1
[1] "a" "d" "g"

$V2
[1] "b" "e" "h"

$V3
[1] "c" "f" "i"
```